# Can Chrome Developer Tools be launched "standalone"? (not linked to a tab)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing a lot of mobile development right now.  To get to the remote debugging, I have to first open devtools for a tab, then go to settings, remote devices.  This opens a new devtools window.  I can then close the other one I never even needed.  I'd like to bypass the unnecessary window if at all possible.

Comment: Open `chrome://inspect/`, get an URL for your device and try using it directly next time. Untested.

Comment: I bookmarked that, it cuts out quite a few clicks (5 > 2). It still opens an unnecessary tab I have to close, but way better. Thanks.

Comment: Not valid in 2022.

Comment: I just checked in Edge (107) and Chrome (108) and `chrome://inspect/` still works fine.  What do you mean not valid?